# About String warning format is not a string literal and no format arguments

Tags: iphone

Hi i am using following code.

```
NSString *quant = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",item.capacity];
NSString *metricUnit = item.metric_Unit;
cell.quantity.text = [quant stringByAppendingFormat:metricUnit];
```

while quant is nsnumber and i m getting a warning named "format is not a string literal and no format arguments" and i m trying many was but did nt success, plzz if any one know how to remove that warning plzz tell ...

Hope your positive response

Comment: You have declared quant as nsstring.. and you are saying it as nsnumber... QUITE CONFUSING.... please tell the datatype of capacity & metric_Unit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning is self-descriptive - api expects format you're passing to `stringByAppendingFormat` function to be a string literal. To avoid this warning you can just append a string (as you don't use format parameters anyway):

```
cell.quantity.text = [quant stringByAppendingString:metricUnit];
```

or

```
cell.quantity.text = [quant stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",metricUnit];
```